# Cannot find a mixed-strategy Nash equilibrium in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have the follow matrix, but whenever I try to calculate the probabilities, they are all.. equal? I can't deduce the formulas any more and I am incredibly confused since I don't think this is how it is done. Can someone point me out what I am doing wrong?

[image]

player 2:
3p+1(1-p) = 3p+1(1-p)
3p+1-1p = 3p+1-1p

player 1:
1q+3(1-q) = 1q+3(1-q)
1q+3-3q=1q+3-3q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This game has only a pure strategy Nash equilibrium of $(T, R)$. There is no reason to mix strategies because changing strategies can not improve either players reward. Note that this would technically be considered a trivial mixed strategy where for example player one plays $T$ with probability 1 and plays $B$ with probability 0.